# 'list' object is not callable error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, genetic-algorithm, callable

I am  working on a genetic algorithm problem. I have selected some competent individual based on their fitness. Now I am trying to breed among the individuals to produce the next generation.

```
def crossover(parent1,parent2):
    parent1=np.random.randint(0,100,20)
    parent2=np.random.randint(0,100,20)
    child1=[]
    child2=[]
    crossover_point=int(np.random.random()*len(parent1))
    for i in range(crossover_point+1):
        child1.append(parent1[i])
        child2.append(parent2[i])
        temp=i
    for i in range(temp+1,len(parent1)):
        child1.append(parent2[i])
        child2.append(parent1[i])
    return child1,child2
def breed_population(selection_result):
    k=len(selection_result)//2
    children=[]
    for i in range(k):
        child=crossover(selection_result[i],selection_result(k-i-1))
        children.append(child)

    return children
selection_result=[10, 8, 19, 10, 5, 1, 11, 14, 17, 8, 16, 16, 11, 8, 17, 13, 11, 10, 8, 11]
p=breed_population(selection_result)
```

Now, I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d2718835d6df> in <module>
     24     return children
     25 selection_result=[10, 8, 19, 10, 5, 1, 11, 14, 17, 8, 16, 16, 11, 8, 17, 13, 11, 10, 8, 11]
---> 26 p=breed_population(selection_result)

<ipython-input-2-d2718835d6df> in breed_population(selection_result)
     19     children=[]
     20     for i in range(k):
---> 21         child=crossover(selection_result[i],selection_result(k-i-1))
     22         children.append(child)
     23 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: `selection_result` is a list, so in line 21 it should be used as `selection_result[k-i-1]`

Comment: I got the answer.

Comment: one observation - in function `crossover` you are always re-initializing the parameters, just dont pass them if you have to give your own values all the time.

Comment: Correct. I am fixing that. There is no point in passing the parameter here.